# CMS images alt and title tags

Tags: magento-1.7, database, cms, seo, media-images

We have a Magento 1.7 with many images in CMS blocks, CMS pages and attributes (like description).
Unfortunately, a lot of these images don't have `alt` or `title` tags.
I want to run a script that would:

1. Get all Images paths that are stored in the database - search for all `<img` tags.
2. Check if they already have an `alt` or `title` tag.
3. If they don't, set the image name as the `alt` and `title` tag.
4. If they have just an `alt` or a `title` tag, use that value to populate the missing tag

**Additional Info**

For some unexplainable reason, some images have an empty `alt` tag `<img src="" alt />`

Comment: I think it is a piece of paid work - to write actual script that will do the job. SO is the place where you can find answers on your problems, but will not do all the job for you.

Comment: Give it a try and write at least some code, dude :)